# How do I pick PDF files in Umbraco 7?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog

I'm working on an Umbraco project, and my requirement is to pick PDF files from the Umbraco admin panel. I've tried **multi url picker** for Umbraco package but it doesn't work properly.

Is there any way to pick and upload PDF files?

Comment: You mean pdf files that are stored on your computer or in your media folder?

Comment: I think you'll need mediapicker

Comment: @mivaweb - in computer..

Comment: And you want to store them in the media section?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the PDF files are in the Media section of Umbraco, you can use the Multiple Media Picker editor that comes with Umbraco to pick the PDF files.

Calling `@Umbraco.Field("multipleMediaPickerPropertyAlias")` in your template will return a comma separated list of Media item ids.  You can use this and `UmbracoHelper.Media` method to get an list of Media items as follows:

```
@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("multipleMediaPickerTest"))
{
    var mediaItemIdList = CurrentPage.multipleMediaPickerTest.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var mediaItems = Umbraco.Media(mediaItemIdList);

    foreach (var mediaItem in mediaItems)
    {
        <a href="@mediaItem.Url">@mediaItem.Name</a><br>
    }
}
```